# Why await includes all other failed promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, promise

I have a fundamental question about how promises work in Node.js (in browsers the behaviour is as expected), consider the following function as an example:

```
async function proc(): Promise<void> {
  const resolve = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0))
  const reject = Promise.reject('reject')

  console.log(await resolve)

  try {
    await reject
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Since the reject gets dequeued faster, it is thrown at `await resolve` and since it is not handled there, we get an unhandled rejection.

Although there are plenty of solutions to work around this, I find this behaviour counter-intuitive. Is there any reason why the object passed to `reject()` is not getting thrown at the time the corresponding promise is `await`ed, similarly how the object passed to `resolve()` is returned at the time of `await`?

I expected `await` to work something like this:

```
await(promise) {
  let result, error;

  promise
    .then((data) => result = data)
    .catch((err) => error = err)

  // wait for promise magic

  if (error != null) {
    throw error
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that nodejs detects unhandled rejections when it gets back to the event loop and there's a rejected promise with no reject handler.  So, when you do `await resolve`, that goes back to the event loop (to process other things while awaiting that promise), but there is no reject handler on the `reject` promise.  So, you get the `unhandled rejection` message.  This is a side effect of how nodejs detects unhandled rejections.  There are better ways to write your code that won't be susceptible to that issue.

Comment: "*Since the reject gets dequeued faster, it is thrown at `await resolve`*" - no it is not?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 , makes sense. For the record, this is easily solvable, I was just goofing around and found this one puzzling. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's something you learn in nodejs promise programming.  Don't ever leave a promise (without a reject handler) sitting in a variable when nodejs can go back to the event loop because it can cause it to detect an unhandled rejection if that promise rejects before there is a handler attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has more to do with how NodeJS responds to "unhandled promise rejections," of which the default recently changed to `throw` in [Node 15](https://nodejs.medium.com/node-js-v15-0-0-is-here-deb00750f278#8929).

Whenever an unhandled [promise] rejection occurs, the following steps are taken ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--unhandled-rejectionsmode)):

1. Emit [`unhandledRejection`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection).
2. If this hook is not set, raise the unhandled rejection as an uncaught exception.

Therefore if you have the following script:

```js
// example.js
async function proc() {
    const resolve = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    const reject = Promise.reject("reject");

    await resolve;
    console.log("Able to `await resolve`");

    try {
        await reject;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Caught an error!');
        console.error(err);
    }
}

proc();
```

That result of executing that script changes depending on what `mode` the `--unhandled-rejections` flag is set to.

If it is set it to `throw` (the default), you see that the program never continues past the `await resolve` line because the rejected promise throws before the promise is fulfilled.

Also note that if you had set `process.on('unhandledRejection', ...)` beforehand, you also wouldn't see the rejected promise throw.

Here is what you are probably seeing when you run the **example.js** script:

```
$ node --unhandled-rejections=throw example.js

node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "reject".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

However, if you run it with the mode set to `warn`, you'll see something like this:

```
$ node --unhandled-rejections=warn example.js

(node:55979) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: reject
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:55979) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
Able to `await resolve`
Caught an error!
reject
(node:55979) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

That is, we are able to get to the `try` block since the rejected promise doesn't throw an uncaught exception.

Comment: "*the resolved promise is never `await`'d*" - it does get to the line where it is `await`ed, it just doesn't continue **past** the line since `resolve` doesn't fulfill before the process dies.

Comment: @romellem thanks for explaining, I actually checked and chromium behaved as I expected, so I can verify that it is Node only and that your explanation and solution above is completely accurate. Appreciate you!

Comment: @kataik Chromium reports the exact same unhandled promise rejection, it just doesn't crash the tab